# dnsmasq - flooding daemon.log with messages

Tags: debian, dnsmasq

I am hoping to use dnsmasq to provide for a wireless AP on Debian Wheezy.

Issue: daemon.log is filling up with repeated 'DHCPREQUEST' and 'DHCPACK' messages from the one test client (win7).

Config file:

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=wlan0,192.168.70.10,192.168.70.200,12h
dhcp-option=252,"\n"
```

This last line was supposed to stop win7 from nagging but it doesn't seem to be working. `daemon.log` is getting these messages every 8-10 seconds.

It will fill up the file system in short order if this continues.

What I've tried:

```
ipconfig /release and /renew on the client
adding the last line to the config file
lots of searching
```

I've seen other references to this message trail but they are usually associated with other DHCP servers.

What step did I miss?

---

EDIT - /var/log/syslog is getting these messages too

---

EDIT - output of dhcp requests logging:

> Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 available DHCP range: 192.168.70.10 -- 192.168.70.200
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 client provides name: brp-s212
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 vendor class: MSFT 5.0
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 DHCPREQUEST(wlan0) 192.168.70.11   00:##:##:##:##:##
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 tags: wlan0
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 DHCPACK(wlan0) 192.168.70.11   00:##:##:##:##:## brp-s212
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 requested options: 1:netmask, 15:domain-name, 3:router, 6:dns-server,
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 requested options: 44:netbios-ns, 46:netbios-nodetype, 47:netbios-scope,
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 requested options: 31:router-discovery, 33:static-route, 121:classless-static-route,
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 requested options: 249, 43:vendor-encap
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 next server: 192.168.70.1
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size:  1 option: 53 message-type  5
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size:  4 option: 54 server-identifier  192.168.70.1
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size:  4 option: 51 lease-time  86400
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size:  4 option: 58 T1  43200
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size:  4 option: 59 T2  75600
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size:  4 option:  1 netmask  255.255.255.0
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size:  4 option: 28 broadcast  192.168.70.255
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size:  4 option:  3 router  192.168.70.1
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size:  4 option:  6 dns-server  192.168.70.1
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size: 11 option: 81 FQDN  03:ff:ff:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size:  1 option: 31 router-discovery  00
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size:  0 option: 47 netbios-scope
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size:  1 option: 46 netbios-nodetype  08
>   Nov 17 09:24:28 odroid-01 dnsmasq-dhcp[3364]: 855385675 sent size:  4 option: 44 netbios-ns  192.168.70.1

Comment: Is the client accepting the offered address? Try ipconfig. The client should only renew every 6 hours or so.

Comment: Client is Windows 7

Comment: The command ipconfig will show the IP address, if any, your Windows 7 has accepted.

Comment: Duh..yes of course.. Ipconfig shows it with a valid address. It keeps asking. For the same one over again.

Answer (score 2):

Option 252 should be the URL for a `.pac` file, something like `http://example.com/wpad.dat`.  This might be causing your Windows 7 system from accepting the DHCP response.

If you don't have a file on a web server, try omitting that option.

You also appear to be missing some standard options.  Try adding these (editted appropriately):

```
dhcp-option=wlan0,3,192.168.70.1                # Router
dhcp-option=6,192.168.70.1,8.8.4.4              # DNS servers
dhcp-option=wlan0,15,wlan.example.com           # Domain
```

These are some additional options I set.

```
dhcp-option=19,0                                # Option ip-forwarding off
dhcp-option=20,0                                # Source routing off
dhcp-option=27,1                                # All sub-nets are local
dhcp-option=31,0                                # Router Discovery off
dhcp-option=42,192.168.70.1                     # NTP time servers
dhcp-option=44,192.168.70.1                     # WINS server
dhcp-option=46,8                                # Netbios node type   
dhcp-option=47                                  # Empty netbios scope.
dhcp-option=119,example.com,com                 # Search List
dhcp-option=252,http://www.example.com/wpad.dat # Autocofig
```

Comment: Have tried it both with and without the 252 line. Same result.

Comment: @ethrbunny I've edited to add some additional options that you may need to set.

Comment: Hmm.. I added these and continue to get a DHCPREQUEST/DHCPACK message on the DHCP server every 10-15 seconds.

Comment: @etherbunny At this point I would break out `tcpdump` or `dhcpdump` and check the contents of the traffic.  These messages should only be generated in response to requests.

Comment: Interesting: I found a reference in another forum to a similar issue(TL;DR). It suggested putting the wlan address and hostname into `/etc/hosts`. I did this and now I get DHCPINFORM/DHCPACK about once a minute instead of the msgs I got before.

Comment: @ethrbunny Is there anything in your dns leases file. (Likley /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases?.  The first field should be the expiry time of the lease.

Comment: I rebuilt the system in question using a newer 'jessie' build. Im starting to believe the issue is more based on `hostapd` instead of dnsmasq.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem on routers running Tomato firmware derivatives for a decade now. I have seen two workarounds so far:

### Use WPAD option 252

Add the extra dnsmasq option for Web Proxy Auto-Discovery, as you noted. This did work for me:

```
dhcp-option=252,"\n"
```

Now I notice that this setting comes baked in, at least on `FreshTomato version 2020.5`:

```
$ grep 252 /etc/dnsmasq.conf                                                                  
dhcp-option=lan,252,"\n"   

$ uname -a                                                                                    
    Linux tomato 2.6.36.4brcmarm #2 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 15 11:45:31 CEST 2020 armv7l Tomato    

$ dnsmasq -v                                                                                  
Dnsmasq version 2.81  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 Simon Kelley                                    
Compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-UBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua
TFTP no-conntrack ipset Tomato-helper auth DNSSEC no-ID loop-detect inotify no-dumpfile
```

But oddly, the messages didn't stop until I added it again.  in:

```
Advanced > DHCP/DNS > Dnsmasq Custom Configuration
```

### Use a Static IP

If you only have a couple of offending hosts, you can just configure them to use a static IP address and bypass dnsmasq-dhcp altogether. For example, on my network it was just a single Windows 7 host. I have another (guest) vlan configured, but there are no hosts on it.

Many users of dnsmasq on similar third-party firmware have reported the same issue with Windows 7 hosts and some apple devices.

In my case, I was seeing it repeat every 2 or 8 minutes for a single host in syslog, with a strange `2,8,2,8...` pattern.

```
Sep2 17:54:26 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPINFORM(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff 
Sep2 17:54:26 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff Windows7Host
Sep2 18:02:22 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPINFORM(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff 
Sep2 18:02:22 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff Windows7Host
Sep2 18:04:26 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPINFORM(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff 
Sep2 18:04:26 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff Windows7Host
Sep2 18:12:22 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPINFORM(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff 
Sep2 18:12:22 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff Windows7Host
Sep2 18:14:27 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPINFORM(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff 
Sep2 18:14:27 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff Windows7Host
Sep2 18:22:22 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPINFORM(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff 
Sep2 18:22:22 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff Windows7Host
Sep2 18:24:27 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPINFORM(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff 
Sep2 18:24:27 tomato daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[.]: DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.1.2 dd:de:ad:be:ef:ff Windows7Host
```